# Read Value from Resource file using String

Tags: c#, resources, enums

I have an enum with some data on it, also I have a resource file with the same data of the enum but using different translation

**Ex.**

```
enum test
{
    Sun =1,
    Mon = 2
}

The resource file : Text.resx

Sun --> Sunday
Mon --> Monday
```

Now I want to get the value from the resource file but not using

```
string data = Resources.Text.Sun;
```

but using my enum value , I have found some code but I have an exception, the code is following :

```
string resourceFile = "~/App_GlobalResources/Text.resx";
string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
string resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(myEnum.ToString());
```

and I got the following Exception

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or
>   the neutral culture) on disk. baseName:
>   ~/App_GlobalResources/Text.resx  locationInfo:   fileName:
>   ~/App_GlobalResources/Text.resx.resources

please help as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The problem is not in your code. System can't find *.resx file to get resourse from it. Check the resource files path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resource is probably be a part of your assembly. Why don't you use the following? `Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(test.Sun.ToString())`

Comment: thanks for hint of using Resources . The 'Resources.ResourceFileNAmeWithoutExtention.KEY_NAMEXXXX' worked for me when my resource file is added to the project

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a local resource and the name of the resource item is Sun, u can write the following

```
GetLocalResourceObject("Sun").ToString();
```

Edited: don't forget to name the resource file as ur webpage file name and use a `App_LocalResources`:
EX: webpage is **Test.aspx** , then your resource file is **Test.aspx.resx**