# C# Resource handling

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have created a resource file using File -> New item > Resource and put 2 keys and 2 values.
If i set it as embedded resource then i can do and receive the value:

```
ResourceName.ResourceManager.GetString("Key");
```

But when i do it when resource is not embedded, i get exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 
'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

How can i create ResourceManager object that initialized itself with the resource i created ?

I tried:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager
(resourceFile, filePath, null);
```

when path and filename  were ok but the object was null and threw exception.

I was following [this read value from source..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644796/read-value-from-resource-file-using-string) but did not work either. file could not be loaded ?

Comment: Why can't you directly use the static property of the resource file.For example you have a key named "ErrorMessage" and your resource file name is "Messages", you can use var error = Messages.ErrorMessage.

Comment: How exactly did you add it? My copy of Visual Studio 2012 doesn't have "New Item" under the "File" menu. If I right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose Add -> New Item, there are 2 options for resources: "Resources File" and "Resource Dictionary (WPF)", neither of which is exactly what you've written. So it's not totally clear what you've done. Picking the former ("Resources File") it works, and I don't get the error. So I'll need a more precise description to offer help.

Comment: @IanGriffiths Right click the project, Add Item > Resource File. ("Visual C# Items")

Comment: @Danny the way you suggested works, but I would also like to have a member i can call and search for keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question that ilansch added in the comments to the original question:

> I would also like to have a member i can call and search for keys

here's one way (assuming you've already added a "Resources File" called "ResourceName.resx" to your project):

```
ResourceSet rs = ResourceName.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
Dictionary<string, object> resources = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(r => (string) r.Key, r => r.Value);

// Can now list all keys, e.g.:
foreach (string key in resources.Keys)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(key);
}

// ...or can find out whether a key is present:
object v;
if (resources.TryGetValue("Key", out v))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(v);
}
```

That loads all of the resources in the resource file into a `Dictionary<string, object>`, and you can then use that to discover keys. This may not be massively efficient though, as it will load the entire set of resources into memory.

If you just want a list of keys, you can do this:

```
string[] keys = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(r => (string) r.Key).ToArray();
```

Not sure if that actually helps, because it's not clear to me what your overall goal is here.