# How to get the key of a resource from a localised string value?

Tags: c#

You can get the value from a resource key with the following:

```
string s = Namespace.ResourceLocation.ResourceFile.KeyName;
```

Is there a way to get the key name from a string value?

Comment: Finding key by value in dictionary does not guarantee unique result... Can you please clarify why do you need that? (possibly just using resource names instead of precompiled accessors would work better in your case).

Comment: It's a bit of an odd ball situation. There's a number of codes with various translations, however the data is introduced into the system by their British English values - the data then needs to be shown in the selected end user language. The best way to show the data is with resource files - and it's only in the introduction phase that I'd like to lookup the original code. In this instance, they are gaurenteed to be unique

Comment: If you start with string why you trying some strange manipulations instead of just getting resource string by that value? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644796/read-value-from-resource-file-using-string)

Comment: Because this is just an interim phase - ultimately, the system will be updated directly with the codes (which matches the resource key), so for the short term, and rather than re-engineer something to only be thrown away in a few months it keeps the future structures in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the resource file and get the keyname using the value.

```
using System.Resources;
using (ResXResourceReader oReader = new ResXResourceReader(ResourceFilePath))
{
      IDictionaryEnumerator oResource = oReader.GetEnumerator();
      while (oResource.MoveNext())
      {
           if (oResource.Value.ToString() == "VALUE")
               return oResource.Key.ToString();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Just a comment here - this doesn't work if the resx file get's compiled into the assembly - the physical resx file needs to remain as part of the project when published.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, from inquisitive_mind's answer I ended up with:

```
var resDict = StronglyTypedResource
                   .ResourceManager
                   .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, false)
                       .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value.ToString());
```

To get my strongly typed resource file into a dictionary - the bit I'd missed initially was to enable `createIfNotExists` to load the resource file.

Then simply query the dictionary:

```
entity.ResourceKeyValue =
    resDict.First(x => x.Value.ToLower() == stringValue.Trim().ToLower()).Key;
```